# Where Can I Download Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I need to develop a simple 64-bit C++ Text to Speech (TTS) program to run on Windows 7 and Vista.  My first step is to try to compile the program from SAPI 5.4 tutorial.  But I cannot find the required SAPI 5.4 packages on my Windows 7 machine.  I searched the Internet and only SAPI 5.1 is available for Windows XP.
[Microsoft Speech Technology page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323805%28v=office.14%29.aspx) claims that “The native-code API for programming the speech engines included in Windows 7.”  The [SAPI 5.4 tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125082) has the following instruction:

```
Step 1. Setting up the Project:  
…  
Code Listing 1  
Next add the paths to SAPI.h and SAPI.lib files. The paths shown are for a 
standard SAPI SDK install. If the compiler is unable to locate either file, 
or if a nonstandard install was performed, use the new path to the files. 
Change the project settings to reflect the paths. Using the Project->Settings. 
menu item, set the SAPI.h path. Click the C/C++ tab and select Preprocessor 
from the Category drop-down list. Enter the following in the "Additional 
include directories": C:\Program Files\Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4\Include.  


To set the SAPI.lib path:    
1.  Select the Link tab from the Same Settings dialog box.  
2.  Choose Input from the Category drop-down list.  
3.  Add the following path to the "Additional library path": 
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4\Lib\i386.  
4.  Also add "sapi.lib" to the "Object/library modules" line. Be sure that the 
    name is separated by a space.   
…
```

The 2 folders from the above instruction do not exist on my Windows 7 PC.  I installed [Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) but these 2 folders are still not there.
What I should do to get the SAPI 5.4 installed on my Windows 7 machine and compiles the program from the above tutorial?
Thank you very much for your help!
David

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Speech SDK 5.4 or SAPI 5.4 is included in the "Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Frameword 4" package.  It can be downloaded from Microsoft Download Center.  After installed the package, the include file is in "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\include" and the library file is in "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64". There is no need to specify these two location when compile the program.  Microsoft's SAPI 5.4 tutorial and some related documents are out of date.